# Semantic UI Button click causing additional page reload

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

I am just exploring on the `Semantic UI` and I came across a button click event in a form and I have witnessed a bizarre behavior.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qnLqdggk/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Semantic UI CDN</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="semantic.css" />
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="semantic.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="margin:1em;">
    <!-- Your Semantic UI Code -->
    <br/><br/>

    <h1 class="ui center aligned icon header">
            First Form
    </h1>

    <form class="ui form"  style="">

        <div class="inline fields" id="ir_num_row_div">
                <div class="three wide field required">
                    <label>Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="five wide field">
                    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your good name goes here..">
                </div>
        </div>


        <div class="inline fields">
            <div class="three wide field required">
                <label>Place</label>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 290px;">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Where are you from ?">
            </div>

            <button style="margin:1em;" class="ui primary button" id="btn_validate">Validate</button>

        </div>

    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#btn_validate").click(function(){
            alert("you clicked me");
            // Why page reloading here ?...
        }); 

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

After clicking the `Validate` button, the page is going for reload additionally after showing the alert messgae.

Where I am making the mistake here ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To prevent a `<button>` element submitting the form, you will need to add a `type="button"` attribute.

An extract from [<button> HTML | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button):

> **type**
>
> The type of the button. Possible values are:
>
> - `submit`: The button submits the form data to the server. **This is the default if the attribute is not specified**, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.
> - `reset`: The button resets all the controls to their initial values.
> - `button`: The button has no default behavior. It can have client-side scripts associated with the element's events, which are triggered when the events occur.
> - `menu`: The button opens a popup menu defined via its designated <menu> element.

Answer (score 0):

The button tag should be a div, according to this comment: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/3493#issuecomment-182349807

Comment: fwiw, I stumbled on this question because my button IS a div and the page is still refreshing. It seemed to work for your fiddle at least.

Comment: If I define the element as `<input type="button"/>` it is working. In case of `<button>` element, still the issue persists.